# Incremental Count and it's position in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a requirement to get incremental counts. I am new to Python so please help me.

I have tried below:

```
Testword = 'foo boo'
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for key in Testword:
    print key, Testword.count(key)
```

Results :

```
f 1
o 4
o 4
  1
b 1
o 4
o 4
```

I would like to get incremented count output in the same input order like

```
f=1
o=1
o=2

b=1
o=3
o=4
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the number of occurences *until* the position, you are currently looking at. Using `Testword[:pos+1]`, you can take the substring until the current position. Hence:

```python
testword = 'foo boo'
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for pos, key in enumerate(testword):
    print(key, testword[:pos+1].count(key))
```

Gives

```
f 1
o 1
o 2
  1
b 1
o 3
o 4
```

Btw, please use python3, not python2.

Comment: Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended are off-topic on this site and should not be answered. If OP edits their post to address the problem and makes their post on-topic, they may make your answer moot. Anyways, on-topic questions get more views and will get you more rep in the long run ;) See this meta discussion for reference: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6604/98493

Comment: This code could do with a Code Review, to remove the \$n^2\$ complexity.